# Similar to a make file but for Windows

Tags: windows, makefile

I needed to know if there is a program which would perform a set of simple tasks which a user can do.

```
For example. I want to copy file1 of folder1 to folder2. And then stop some services. And then copy file2 to folder3. If folder3 does not exist then folder4. And then download something and then maybe uninstall/install something. 

May I please know if there is a program which can do that. 

Thanking you.
```

Best regards, 
Satya Ashok Kumar.

Answer (score 0):

There is make for windows, too. nmake as part of Visual studio, gnu make from cygwin or mingw. Or something newer, like cmake.

But what you describe looks more like a simple batch file (like a shellscript on Unix) would be sufficient. The interpreter for that, cmd.exe, is already part of windows. More advanced: Powershell.